# 'police investigation' or 'police examination'?

Tags: vocabulary

I think 'police investigation' is a more frequently used terms in America,
but is 'police examination' also used? or is not a right expression?

Answer (score 3):

A 'police investigation' is the term for when the police are looking into a particular case/crime.

'Police examination' is not a common expression, but if I heard it, I would think it referred to standardized testing taken by police officers, like in [this link](https://www1.nyc.gov/site/nypd/careers/police-officers/po-exam.page).